# Add batch script on shutdown - only works on restart

Tags: windows, batch-file

I've added my .bat script to gpedit.msc -> shutdown, but it's not working when I'm turning off my computer. Strange thing however is that it works on restarting system (which I dont want to).

How to fix this? Why is it working in such way?

Comment: Edit your question and post your code !

Comment: the code does not matter - I'm asking why the script isnt even run on shutdown

Comment: As Hackoo told you, the code is important, is the script on a maped drive? have the system account access rights to the path/program/registry? How can anyone figure out what's going on if you only say _it is't working_. Please read [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: *"I want to cook a meal; what ingredients do I need?"* - hard to answer without having any idea what meal I want to cook, right?